# How do i use .sort() to create a relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I am using the kaminari gem for pagination. I have a resources controller which paginates perfectly (due to the simple nature of the ordering). That can be seen here:

```
@resources = Resource.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

That just sorts them by latest first. when i do .class it appears thats an activerecord::relation

On my tags though, I want to sort them by a relationship (the number of resources assigned to that tag)

```
@tags = Tag.all.sort{|a, b| b.number_of_resources <=> a.number_of_resources}.page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

It gives me the error however `undefined method`page' for #`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958558/how-to-sort-authors-by-their-book-count-with-activerecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tag.all` returns an Array, hence your #page call failing, as it expects an ARel relation.

If #number_of_resources maps to a DB column, then all you need to do is:

```
Tag.order('number_of_resources').page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

If it's not, you either need to add it to the Tag database table, or just do your sort/paginate in Ruby rather than using kaminari.  This will be feasible if the number of tags is under ~1000 or so.

If you do add the info to the db, check out this post: [Counter Cache for a column with conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347323/counter-cache-for-a-column-with-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like: 1) joins the two tables, 2) group rows by tag, 3) count how many rows belongs to each group, 4) order using that new column with the count

you should make a good sql statement and then you can call pagination