# Rails order Post by def in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to order posts based on the total votes it has. This is what I have in the Post Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :url
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true
  has_many :votes

  def vote_number
    votes.where(direction: "up").count - votes.where(direction: "down").count
  end
end
```

And this is what I attempted to do in the Post Controller:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.last(10).order('vote_number')
end
```

Nevertheless I get this error from the index:

```
undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x3787158>
```

The other questions in Stack Overflow resolved this problem by making the calculation in the Post Controller but I can not do it because votes are arrays and not integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try counter cache. 
You can read more about it from the following links -

[How to sort authors by their book count with ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958558/how-to-sort-authors-by-their-book-count-with-activerecord)

http://hiteshrawal.blogspot.com/2011/12/rails-counter-cache.html

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Counter cache only works inside rails. If you updated from outside application you might have to do some work around.

Comment: Thanks @Dev for the answer but after looking at the resources you posted out I don't understand how counter cache can be use to solve the problem...

Comment: You can use the counter cache column to get the updated value of (vote_up - vote down) and then use it for the sort.
To see about how to override the update function of the counter cache you can check here for reference - http://blog.douglasfshearer.com/post/17495285851/custom-counter-cache-with-conditions

Comment: The problem is that I can not just do vote_up - vote_down. Check how the score is defined: `def vote_number
    votes.where(direction: "up").count - votes.where(direction: "down").count
  end`

Comment: I didn't mean for you to use vote_up and vote_down directly. What i meant is for you to create the counter_cache (for example vote_difference ) column. And then override the counter_cache update method to update the vote_difference to be the value of (no. of vote up - no. of vote down). So by doing like this. every time the vote is created or updated the vote_difference column will be update with appropriate value. And you use it for the sort in a appropriate manner.

Comment: I have written another answer with example for this. I hope this might help.

Comment: ok got what you mean. Sorry I am a noob. So let me check the blogs and your code and see if I can solve it your way. I already found a solution but it presents a number of problems like I can not use  `last(10)`

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to solve it. Instead of using order I used sort_by.

Instead of having this in the Post Controller:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.last(10).order('vote_number')
end
```

I used sort_by:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all.sort_by{|post|-post.vote_number}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`first`, `last` and `all` execute query. Insert order always before those three.

Comment: I tried your solution as `def index
   @posts = Post.order('vote_number').last(10)
 end` but it gives me this error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: vote_number: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  ORDER BY vote_number`

Comment: And you sure your posts table have this column? Or this is relation? Maybe there are migrations that hasn't be executed?

Comment: Hi @Eraden you are right there are no tables. I wanted to do it without creating a new table but I guess that does not work with `order`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :url
  attr_reader :vote_difference # getter
  attr_writer :vote_difference # setter
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true

  #more class methods here      


  def after_save
    self.update_counter_cache
  end

  def after_destroy
    self.update_counter_cache
  end

  def update_counter_cache
    post.vote_difference = post.comments.where(direction: 'up').count - post.comments.where(direction: 'down').count
    post.save
  end
end
```

Now you can sort by vote_difference when you query up.
for example -

```
posts = Post.order(:vote_difference, :desc)
```

I haven't check the correctness of my code yes. If you find any issues please let me know. I am sure it can be adapted to make it works.

If you follow this pattern to use counter_cache you might will to run a migration to add a vote_difference column, and another migration to update the vote_difference column for previous created post.

Comment: you were really helpfull to solve the problem at the end. But I am not sure if I am using counter cache right. Basically what I finally did was create the new column,use counter cache in the votes model (not sure if being hepful), and then every time a vote is made  call update_attribute before it is saved...

Comment: You should call update_attribute after it is saved or deleted to be precise, to cover up the delete condition also.