# rails order by has_many count for a resource

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have models Author, Books

Author:

```
has_many :books, as: :resource, class_name: "Book"
```

Book:

```
Book(id: integer, resource_id: integer, resource_type: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

For an author, resource_id will be author id, resource_type will be "Author".

so, author_instance.books will return books.

I tried using counter_cache from [How to sort authors by their book count with ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958558/how-to-sort-authors-by-their-book-count-with-activerecord) but its returning error "books_count" not available.

Even this didnt work:

```
Author.joins(:books).order("(select count(*) from books) DESC").distinct
```

So, how to get authors order by books count.

Comment: Did you add books_count to Author?

Comment: No, I didnt, where should I add in Author, full syntax please ?

Comment: Add a books_count integer column on your authors table

Comment: You can use an SQL Alias

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use an [SQL alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) to populate the `books_count` attribute:

```
Author.joins(:books).select("authors.*, count(books.*) as books_count").order(books_count: :desc).distinct
```

You can see how this works with this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins)